# Boot a hard drive extracted from a pc as a virtual machine

Tags: linux, usb, virtualization, qemu

I want to use `qemu-x86_64` to boot `/dev/sdb`, which is a drive which has an OS with bootloader on it. But I can't seem to get this to work.

```sh
$ qemu-x86_64 /dev/sdb
Error while loading /dev/sdb: Permission denied
$ sudo su
# qemu-x86_64 /dev/sdb
Error while loading /dev/sdb: Permission denied
# exit
$ qemu-x86_64 -hdb /dev/sdb
qemu: unknown option 'hdb'
$ qemu-x86_64 --disk /dev/sdb
qemu: unknown option 'disk'
$ qemu-x86_64 -drive file=/dev/sdb
qemu: unknown option 'drive'
$ qemu-x86_64 -usb -usbdevice disk:/dev/sdb
qemu: unknown option 'usb'
$ qemu-x86_64 -device usb disk:/dev/sdb
qemu: unknown option 'device'
$ qemu-x86_64 -device usb-storage,drive=/dev/sdb
qemu: unknown option 'device'
```

It seems like every single post on this site is simply wrong. None of the commands I found worked. How do I do this seemingly simple thing?

I do not understand the manpage at all. `man qemu` seems to suggest that `-hdb` should just... work? But it doesn't.

Comment: Hi @AnnoyinC, it's more easy to guess what is happen if you ask the following questions: what qemu version are you using? the device is mounted? if it's mounted, what mounted options do you use? Thanks.

Comment: @AndrésMorales Not mounted. Just a USB-3 to sata interface, one of those "hard drive docks". Version qemu-system v6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The executable you are running `qemu-x86_64` is for running x86-64 *executables*, not system images. It tries to dynamically recompile the given executable for running on your platform. If you had an ARM Ubuntu image and you were running an x86-64 executable then that is what that particular program is for.

You need to use `qemu-system-x86_64` which should do the work necessary to set up a *system* including peripherals.

In theory:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=/dev/sdb
```

For more infomration see the [QEMU *System* quickstart guide.](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/quickstart.html)

Comment: This achieved something! Now a window pops up but it seems to get stuck at "Booting from Hard Disk..." any ideas? I also added `,format=raw`

Comment: Is it truly stuck or is it taking time? What kind of system are you booting? What OS? Is the disk MBR or GPT?

Comment: If the disk is from a UEFI system then you may need to tell QEMU to boot with a UEFI bios. Instructions can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52996/how-to-boot-efi-kernel-using-qemu-kvm

Comment: if you're writing to `/dev/` you'd need to use the `root` I believe.